# .value returns undefined instead of proper html value

Tags: javascript, html

This function keeps returning the value as undefined, so I abstracted it into this simple HTML structure and I still can't figure out why it's giving me a value of `undefined`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="shoppingCartInner" class="cartItem">
        <div class="col-lg-4" id="0">
            <div class="cartOpenImage" name="openImage"></div>
            <div class="cartOpenImageNumber">
                <label name="openNumberLabel">Item Number:</label>
                <div name="openNumberValue">0008</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cartOpenItemSupplier">
                <label name="openSupplierLabel">Supplier:</label>
                <div name="openSupplierValue"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cartOpenItemDetails">
                <div name="openDetails">Description: Test ITEM</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cartOpenItemMfr">
                <label name="openMfrLabel">MFR / MFR Part Number:</label>
                <div name="openMfrValue">/</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cartOpenItemQuantity">
                <label name="openQuantityLabel">Quantity:</label>
                <div name="openQuantityValue">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cartDelete">
                <div onclick="removeItem(this);" class="btn btn-red" id="btn-0" value="1">Remove Item</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
<script>
function removeItem(el) {
    var y = el.value;
    alert(y);
};
</script>
```

details because stackoverflow would now allow me to submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's simple:
div's are not input elements therefore they do not have a value property.
to get the value from that element you have two options:
1) change the element from div to:

```
<input type="button" ...
```

2) try to access the attribute using the getAttribute("value") method, example:

```
function removeItem(el) {
    var y = el.getAttribute("value");
    alert(y);
};
```

but the "right" way do it would be using the input element

Comment: I feel like swearing. thank you. I completely blanked on that.

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
var y = el.getAttribute("value");
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cRrak/1/)